# How do I use checkboxes to run a FullCalendar method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar and I want to make a menu on the side of it with checkboxes that the user can uncheck in order to hide certain events on the calendar. This is what I have but it doesn't work. What I'm trying to do is make it so that when the user unchecks the "events" checkbox the "events" eventSource is removed.

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventSources: [
        {
            url: "my url",
            editable: true,
            id: "events",
        }
                    ]
    }); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="menu">
    <form name="display">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cal_type" id="events" checked>Events</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cal_type" id="rto" checked>Vacations and time-off</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cal_type" id="goals" checked>Goals</p>
    </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            if ($('events').is(':unchecked')) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', "my url" )
            }
        </script>

</div>
```